# Commutative diagram, what does the direction of the arrows $\circlearrowleft$ or $\circlearrowright$ imply?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, group-isomorphism

I have a commutative diagram: $f_*\circ \phi = \psi \circ Df$. I have seen commutative diagrams with a circle in the middle. But what does the direction of the arrows $\circlearrowleft$ vs $\circlearrowright$, and how do I determine which is suitable for this diagram?

EDIT2: It is possible that the direction of the error does not mean anything.

EDIT1: Here is an example of the sort of thing I am referring to:

[image: Comutative diagram]

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean (though maybe it's because I'm a novice to such things). Do you have an example you could show us and why specifically said example is confusing?

Comment: In my experience, an arrow (or circle) in a diagram simply indicates commutativity - the direction has no significance. As Eevee Trainer said, if you have seen situations in which the two are distinct, it would be helpful to provide these examples.

Comment: Thanks, I dont know if the direction would mean anything. I have edited the question to clarify. If this is indeed the answer, I propose that you submit this as the answer if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, diagrams drawn with an arrow (oriented in any direction) indicate commutativity of the given diagram - the orientation of the arrow itself is irrelevant. You might also see a circle in the center of a diagram used to indicate the same thing. However, I think it is more common to simply state in words that the diagram is commutative.

In fact, this notation has become so prevalent that if I see any diagram drawn where there are multiple paths from one point to another, I almost automatically assume the diagram is commutative! Personally, I get the willies whenever I draw a diagram that doesn't commute, and I think if you encounter a non-commutative diagram in the wild, the author will (or at least should) make it abundantly clear that it doesn't commute.